# How can I build histogram with proportion values in y-axis?

Tags: r, charts, histogram, frequency, axis-labels

I am experimenting with **ggplot** package in **R** language.
My task is to plot the chart shown in the picture from this excellent paper:
http://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/engmat/2012/seminario/artigos2012/Luis_Ferreira/Using%20logistic%20regression%20to%20estimate%20the%20influence%20of%20accident.pdf

Can you please give me some hint on how to plot this?
Thank you in advance

[image: Example of the plot I need to build in R language]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
# Category names
my.names <- c("test1","test2","test3")

# Example data
data <- runif(length(my.names))

# Normalize the example data as a percentage of the total
data.norm <- data / sum(data)

# Use barplot to plot the results, plot without an x axis
x <- barplot(data.norm,names.arg=my.names,xaxt="n")

# Apply new x labels rotated by 45 degrees
text(cex=1, x=x-0.1, y=-0.05, my.names, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to modify code to get labels in x-axis in 45 degree rotated? Regards

Comment: I edited my response above to include labels rotated 45 degrees.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
bp<-barplot(data.norm, beside=TRUE, col=c("grey10","grey20","grey30","grey40","grey50","grey60","grey70","grey80","grey90","grey80","grey70","grey60",))text(bp, par("usr")[3], labels=my.names, srt=45, pos=2, xpd=TRUE,offset=0.01)
```

It is working fine for my purpose.Hope this helps to the others
Regards